# Color segmentation using EmguCV

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, emgucv, threshold

Context:
The goal is to create a script which tracks convexHullDefects to count the number of fingers currently being tracked and return this number to Unity.

Question: I am trying to do threshold on an HSV image, since HSV is thought to be the best color space for threshold. However, with the current code, i seem to be tracking much more than just green which is my target segmentation for a person wearing a green glove. My brown beard is being tracked as an example. What seems to be the issue?

Further information:
Hue,Saturation and value gained from the site "colorizer.org"

[image: Example of current result]

Code:

---

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Features2D;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Aruco;

public class GestureTrackingScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public VideoCapture cap;
    public RawImage camImage;
    int iteration = 0;
    double hueMin = 102.0;
    double hueMax = 126.0;
    double saturationMin = 76.0;
    double saturationMax = 100.0;
    double valueMin = 25.0;
    double valueMax = 100.0;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Startup initiated...");
        cap = new VideoCapture(0); // instantiate a webcamera
        cap.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Fps, 30); // The FPS of the camera

        Debug.Log("Startup finished. Running...");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Image<Hsv, byte> imgInput = cap.QueryFrame().ToImage<Hsv, byte>(); // the input image (frame from camera)


        imgInput = imgInput.ThresholdToZero(new Hsv(hueMin, saturationMin, valueMin));
        imgInput = imgInput.ThresholdToZeroInv(new Hsv(hueMax, saturationMax, valueMax));


        MemoryStream _memory = new MemoryStream();
        imgInput.Bitmap.Save(_memory, imgInput.Bitmap.RawFormat);
        Texture2D camera = new Texture2D(400, 400);
        camera.LoadImage(_memory.ToArray());
        camImage.texture = camera;
        camImage.material.mainTexture = camera;
        Debug.Log("Ping Number " + iteration);
        iteration++;

    }
}
```

---

Comment: valueMin is too low

Comment: @Wouter, Increasing the value all the way to 80, still shows it tracking the grey ceiling, and my brown beard, none of which are green, so adjusting the 'valueMin' does not seem to be the solution?